# Is there a 64 bit to 32 bit USB adapter, to connect devices that don't connect to 64 bit machines?

Tags: usb, 32-vs-64-bit, palm

My Palm's synch cable does not work with USB ports on 64 bit computers, and I've seen confirmations online that it does not work for other people as well. Is there by any chance an adapter that could convert the 64 bit USB port into 32 bit one?

Comment: What makes you think it is the 64/32 that is causing the problem and  not USB1/USB2/USB3 etc? What Palm device is it? What computer are you connecting it to? What does "not work" mean? What OS are you using? Could you link to these "confirmations"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confused here on what the problem is. USB doesn't care if the operating system is 32 bit. 64 bit, 16 bit or 256 bit.

What the problem is: there are no 64 bit drivers for your device. You might be able to use a VM, like Windows 7s XP mode to load the 32 bit drivers and OS.

Comment: I can confirm that you can forward a USB device directly to XP mode and use it inside the vm just fine. I had some legacy hardware that did not have 64 bit drivers and this solution worked fine for me.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, it should. I have seen a couple exceptions where the correct driver for some reason would not work in XP Mode... but these were very odd programs that relied on virtual com-ports for USB devices to work with a 16 bit application.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it has nothing to do with the USB Port, but rather your USB drivers. If you right click on the installer, and go to Properties, select Compatibility and choose Windows XP or try another one if that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: This won't help if its a device driver problem.